3v3 voltage drops when connecting leds
I am especially new with electronics.
I am building a model airplane and would like to give it lights that can be controlled and stuff.
So, for now I am using an Adafruit Huzzah feather (ESP8266). Now I have the problem that when lighting multiple leds, they start dimming.
So I went on to investigate. I connected my three interior leds directly to the 3v3 output and I saw a drop from 3.4v to 3.10v more or less. I have connected my leds in the following way:
I have 3 white leds (0306 size).
The negative leads of the leds are connected to two 10 Ohm resistors in parallel each (so In total I have 6 resistors).The end of the resistors are connected to the emiter of a 2N2222 transistor. The collector is connected to GND and finally, the base is connected to 3v3 through a 1k Ohm resistor. The positive leads of the leds are connected to 3v3.
The huzzah should be able to handle 400mA and my multimeter says I am drawing around 25mA (maximum 75mA if I am to follow the datasheet of the leds).
I replaced also the huzzah feather for a D-SUN step down converter and also that one gives me a drop of like 3.6 to 3.3 or something and the power source drops to like 4.9 (from 5). My power source is an adapter of 5v 1A. Odd thing is, when I connect my huzzah which draws like 80mA the voltage drop like to 4.99 or so.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?
The led I am using is and specs acc to the seller website is:
"WTN-0603-300w"
max current 25mA
and max voltage 3.5V
Update this is the schematic, so you mean to say I have connected the emitter and collector wrong?


Draw us a schematic. Your transistor is upside down as described.

Schematic drawn. Is this indeed incorrect?

Yes. Swap the emitter and collector.

First, never connect LEDs to a power supply without current limiting. That's why your supply dropped when you did that: you connected white LEDs with a nominal Vf of 3.1V across your 3.3V supply, which dragged that rail down to the LED's forward voltage.
Speaking of which, the color of LEDs you choose makes a difference in how you power them. The color affects the forward voltage (Vf) seen across the LED. Generally, the shorter the wavelength, the higher the Vf:

from https://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/
You can see the curve for white has a critical point of abut 3.0V.  The chart is only an example. You'll find that white LEDs have stated Vf of 3V to 3.2V or so. Consult your LED data sheet for its actual I vs. Vf curve.
The challenge comes when your LED Vf is somewhere close to your supply voltage, say 3.3V as you're trying to make work. The LEDs with larger forward drops, such as blue or white, will be hard to manage at that voltage. They will require small-value load resistors, and thus be more sensitive to any supply variation. There just isn't enough 'overhead' to make the load resistor large enough for a consistent current.
Things get even worse when you add a transistor. It adds a collector-emmiter drop (Vce) of about 0.2~0.4V or so. This takes away even more overhead.
Bottom line: if you care about consistent brightness, you need at least 4V to run white LEDs if you're using a dropping resistor to set the current.
How to fix it? Some ideas:

Use a higher supply voltage (e.g., 5V) for the LEDs. Perfectly ok if you're using low-side drive transistors like the 2N2222. (Note: connect the emitter to ground, not the collector, and use base current limiting resistor).
Use a 'boost' LED driver for lots of LEDs (wire them in series). Might not be what you want if you need the LEDs to be separate, but would be ok if they blink together.
For a couple of LEDs, use a flying-cap charge pump converter. This would be good if you need separate LED control.
Consider using a different color with a lower Vf.


the boost LED driver seems a good option, can you suggest an IC? I have no clue where to look. Thanks a lot for your help!

Would the MIC2287C be a good option? Do I understand correctly that if I connect this one to a 3.3v source and connect 3 leds in series it will supply 10.5v and 25mA?
